# Builtin objects with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

Does anyone know of a way to mix static object instances with those managed by NHibernate.  I have an application where I use the repository pattern to manage db object instances, and those instances have some complex many-many, one-many, and many-one relationships.  There are some scenarios where I'd like to have a guaranteed object (like a "User" type instance of "sys_user", for example).  The instance must be able to participate in relationships, and I'm willing to have a hardcoded primary key for the few objects I want.

Basically I'm looking for a way to make my repository intermingle statically defined objects into the output, so if I ask for a list of "User"s i get the static "sys_user" plus those defined in the database.  Furthermore, I'd like to be able to have that "sys_user" participate in a relationship with DB objects, i.e. - MyClass("db instance").UserProperty == "sys_user" instance, as defined by a fk on the MY_CLASS db table with a special value (say -1)

In essence, this is just a way to avoid an installation time requirement of pre-loading predefined objects that the app expects into the DB, as well as preventing them from being modified after installation.  I want to code some logic that relies on special instances being present, and not allow users of the app to inadvertantly break that contract.

Comment: Have you found a way to solve this issue? I'm working exactly in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

this should be exactly the case you describe, no need for repository though, just NHibernate http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/08/from-db-to-ram-wellknowinstancetype.html